# How do I handle an AJAX POST on Google App Engine Python 2.5 with webapp.RequestHandler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery

Quick Summary: I'm creating a Chrome extension that talks to a Python 2.5 runtime application on App Engine that queries an SQL database in Google Cloud SQL. Tutorials for App Engine are largely of the getting started variety, and I can't find any tutorials on how to properly handle an AJAX post to the app.

- Design: Chrome Extension input creates an AJAX Post > Python App > SQL DB.
- Python runtime: 2.5
- Host: App Engine hosts app, Cloud SQL hosts SQL database

The Chrome extension is making the AJAX call, but nothing is happening on App Engine.

When running the Python app directly from it's URL (I have test code that allows me to submit a variable to the search class directly) it's able to return the correct results, so the query and database connection work.

The issue I'm having is that I'm:

(a) Not sure if my AJAX request is even hitting the Python app

(b) Not sure if I'm handling the AJAX request correctly (i.e. reading in the data from it and responding with the output)

I've poured through the documentation and examples online but I can't find one that really outlines how to get an AJAX query to interact with a hosted Python app on AppEngine. If anyone sees any glaring errors or can point me towards relevant documentation I'd be very grateful!

Chrome Extension HTML

```
<head>
    <script src='jquery-1.5.1.js'></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function storeInput(value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<url>'
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'term': value},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('boom: ', data);
                //var response = '<p class="desc_line"><span class="desc_title">Name: </span><span class="desc_text">' + eval(data) + '</p>';
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('no chance');
            }
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        //when the page loads
        $('.input-form').live('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formInput = $(this).find('.term-input').val();
            storeInput(formInput);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

App Engine Python code

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import cgi
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import rdbms
from google.appengine.api import files
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from django.utils import simplejson
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

_INSTANCE_NAME = '<instance>'

def Parse

# redacted since this works fine to work through strings passed to it and turn them into proper SQL queries. 

class Search(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        #Create connection to database
        conn = rdbms.connect(instance=_INSTANCE_NAME, database='salesinfo')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # ideally set the body of the AJAX call to a variable but thats not working
        user_input = self.request.body 

        # Parse input
        sql_query = []
        for value in Parse(user_input):
            sql_query.append(value)

            # Try first query
            cursor.execute(sql_query[0])

            # If first query yields no results, try the second query
            if cursor.rowcount < 1:
                cursor.execute(sql_query[1])

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            output = row[0]
            self.response.out.write(output) # ideally respond with the result

        conn.close()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                    [('/', Search)], #removed request
                                    debug=True)

def main():

    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with app engine but can you drop in a debugger and see if it is hitting? did you try to set up print statements to see if it is hitting your python? can you see web requests using chrome developer tools with a chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

Too many possible problems here. I think you are trying to do too many things at once. Your code, at the first glance, makes sense.

I'd start by running the backend app locally and checking if the AJAX code is correct before bundling it inside a Chrome extension. I'm not sure if it's easy to debug in there (I'd suspect it is, but I never tried). In any case, by running the JavaScript code against your local dev server, you'll get a better idea if you are hitting the server. It will also be easier to see what's going on.

You can also try to do the AJAX call with a XmlHTTPRequest. This would remove jQuery from the equation.

Also, the logging module is your friend - you can - and should - log debugging events during debugging.